# How to get rid of circular/cyclic dependencies in TIBCO Spotfire?

Tags: r, dependencies, circular-dependency, spotfire, terr

I have two tables that are linked via a relation (edit -> data table properties -> relations). One contains some raw data, and the other contains aggregated data (calculation on the value).

---

You can see some examples below. Here, data are linked on "category" column.

```
RAW DATA
category | id | value
---------+----+------
   A     |  1 |  10
   A     |  2 |  20
   A     |  3 |  30
   A     |  4 |  30
   B     |  1 |  20
   B     |  2 |  20

COMPUTED DATA
category | any_calculation  //aggregation of raw data based on category
---------+----------------
   A     |       10
   B     |       20
```

---

To do the calculation, I use a R/TERR function that take **raw data** as an input, and that output **computed data**.

Then I display **raw data** in a scatter plot (one per category), and I add a curve that is taken from the column "any_calculation" of the **computed data**.

---

My main problem is that my table with computed data isn't filled by the R/TERR script. The cause is, in my opinion, the cyclic dependency between those two tables.

Do you have any idea/workaround/fix ?

I should also add that I can't do the calculation in the scatter plot (huge calculation). I use Spotfire 7.8.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a table can't be modified/edited by different sources, that is to say multiple scripts (R and Python) can't have the same table as an output.

To fix my problem, I created a new table in one of my script. Then I created a relation between this table and the other one from the other script.